# Can I get a ratio from a selection in sql?

Tags: mysql

I will revise the question with an appropriate name once I'm certain how to communicate what I want.

I have a table called batch_log where people start and stop the work on a batch. Each entry looks like this:

```
"id";"batch_id";"userid";"start_time";"end_time";"time_elapsed"
"99980";"cd9e4c9e-d8bb-4983-64f4-4e777b451b93";"phastie";"2011-09-22 08:54:34";"2011-09-22 10:07:07";"01:12:33"
```

What I really want to do is for a particular person select how long they have tracked compared to the total time for that batch so that I can give them credit for that much of the estimated time. Is there a way to do this in sql?

EDIT[Ended up doing the following:]

```
SELECT user_time_by_batch.batch_id, userid, user_time_by_batch / total_time_by_batch FROM
(
  SELECT SUM(time_elapsed) user_time_by_batch, userid, batch_id
  FROM batch_log
  Where start_time between "2011-08-01" and now()
  and end_time is not null and time_elapsed BETWEEN "00:00:00" AND "10:00:00"
    and batch_id not in ("-1", "-2", "-3", "-4", "-5", "-6", "-7", "-8", "-9", "-10", "-11", "-12", "-13")
  GROUP BY batch_id, userid
) user_time_by_batch
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT SUM(time_elapsed) total_time_by_batch, batch_id
  FROM batch_log
  Where start_time between "2011-08-01" and now() 
    and end_time is not null and time_elapsed BETWEEN "00:00:00" AND "10:00:00"
    and batch_id not in ("-1", "-2", "-3", "-4", "-5", "-6", "-7", "-8", "-9", "-10", "-11", "-12", "-13")

  GROUP BY batch_id
) total_time_by_batch
ON user_time_by_batch.batch_id = total_time_by_batch.batch_id
```

Comment: do you mean you want to compute time_elapsed/(end_time - start_time) ? If you do then it is relatively straightforward as long as you know that subtracting one date from the other gives you a duration in days.

Comment: No he wants to compute (time_elapsed_on_batch_id_for_user id / total_time_elapsed_for_batch_id). Note `time_elapsed` == `(end_time - start_time)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you need

```
SELECT user_id, user_time_by_batch / total_time_by_batch FROM
(
  SELECT SUM(time_elapsed) user_time_by_batch, user_id, batch_id
  FROM batch_log
  GROUP BY batch_id, user_id
) user_time_by_batch
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT SUM(time_elapsed) total_time_by_batch, batch_id
  FROM batch_log
  GROUP BY batch_id
) total_time_by_batch
ON user_time_by_batch.batch_id = total_time_by_batch.batch_id
```

Comment: This is great beon, but it doesn't seem to work though when I try to add conditions to it.

Comment: SELECT userid, user_time_by_batch / total_time_by_batch, batch_id FROM
(
  SELECT SUM(time_elapsed) user_time_by_batch, userid, batch_id
  FROM batch_log
  WHERE batch_log.userid = "bclements"
  GROUP BY batch_id, userid
) user_time_by_batch
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT SUM(time_elapsed) total_time_by_batch, batch_id
  FROM batch_log
  WHERE batch_log.userid = "phastie"
  GROUP BY batch_id
) total_time_by_batch
ON user_time_by_batch.batch_id = total_time_by_batch.batch_id

Comment: how would you add conditions to this? As in, only batches within x time?

Comment: Scratch that, I was trying to add the condition outside of the inner join, I didn't understand the way you were doing it. Thanks for such a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
select batch_id, userid, SUM(end_time - start_time) AS total_user_contribution
FROM batch_log
GROUP BY batch_id, userid
```

will get you the individual user contributions on a per-batch basis. To get the total time for a batch, you could either sum up the individual contributions as you retrieve the data from the above query, or run a separate query to calculate the sum there.